# Finding a method to bypass, "PERMISSION_DENIED", "The caller does not have permission"

Tags: google-forms-api

So I have an old account that has been disabled a couple weeks ago and I had a Google Forms survey. The survey has view analytics enabled, but it isn't shared with anyone. I tried using Google Forms API to extract the responses, but the Forms API returns me with, "PERMISSION_DENIED", "The caller does not have permission". Unfortunately, I don't have any way to get into my old account to view the responses individually. Is there a way that I can bypass this error or is there a different method that I can use to view the responses individually? Thank you

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Comment: Any solution you find is probably going to involve social engineering of some kind. If you're part of an organization, try talking to your admin. If you're doing this on your own, you'll probably want to figure out who to talk to at google.

Comment: The problem is that the owner of the google forms is my old account that has been disabled. I am unable to access it and there is no way for that account to automatically give permission to someone.